# Testing Symfony custom maker (maker bundle)

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, symfony-console

I'm trying to make a custom maker with the Symfony make bundle.

The maker command looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Maker;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\ConsoleStyle;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\DependencyBuilder;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Generator;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\InputConfiguration;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Maker\AbstractMaker;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Str;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;


final class MakeCustomEntity extends AbstractMaker
{
  public static function getCommandName(): string
  {
    return 'make:custom-entity';
  }

  public static function getCommandDescription(): string
  {
    return 'Creates a new entity';
  }

  public function configureCommand(Command $command, InputConfiguration $inputConf)
  {
    $command
      ->addArgument('entity-class', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, sprintf('Choose a name for your entity class (e.g. <fg=yellow>%s</>)', Str::asClassName(Str::getRandomTerm())));
  }

  public function generate(InputInterface $input, ConsoleStyle $io, Generator $generator)
  {

  }

  public function configureDependencies(DependencyBuilder $dependencies)
  {
    $dependencies->addClassDependency(
      Annotation::class,
      'doctrine/annotations'
    );
  }
}
```

So far so good, the custom maker shows up when listing all commands.

However I would like to write a test for this maker (inspired from the tests I have found on the bundles github):

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Maker;

use App\Maker\MakeCustomEntity;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Test\MakerTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Test\MakerTestDetails;

class MakeCustomEntityTest extends MakerTestCase
{
  public function getTestDetails()
  {
    yield 'entity_full_custom_namespace' => [
      MakerTestDetails::createTest(
        $this->getMakerInstance(MakeCustomEntity::class),
        [
          // entity class name
          '\App\Domain\Entity\Test\Test',
        ]
      )
        ->assert(function (string $output, string $directory) {
          $this->assertStringContainsString('created: src/Domain/Entity/Test/Test.php', $output);
        }),
    ];
  }
}
```

When I try to run this test I get the following warning and test doesn't fail even though it should:

```
The data provider specified for Tests\Maker\MakeCustomEntityTest::testExecute is invalid.
You have requested a non-existent service "maker.maker.make_custom_entity". Did you mean one of these: "maker.maker.make_authenticator",...
```

Is this the correct way to testing custom makers? What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem? I have exactly the same problem